# node-gyp failing every time because of bad build tools directory

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, gyp

I've been struggling with this for several hours, and came with no solution.

Basically, when I try to install a node module depending on `node-gyp`, it fails every time - because it knows about a non-existent python directory, which is pointing to my old user dir.

I've changed my username, because node has had problems with it - because of `ł` character in it, which it can't recognize.
So, it points to `C:\Users\Micha�\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe` but it should point somewhere else and **I want to change that**. I've already lurked through system variables, the PATH itself, but I have no clues.

Any ideas how to change that damn directory and bring node-gyp back to life? My time is running up and my boss is not very happy about it.

Comment: Changing your username does not change your user directory name. I'm not sure how to change this, but I know that changing the username does not do this.

Comment: Or are you saying you did already change this folder name and you want node-gyp to point to the new folder instead?

Comment: I made a new account and I want to fix it up - point to the new folder.

Comment: If it's a new account shouldn't you reinstall windows build tools?

Comment: Pretty sure I did that before, but I'm gonna do it again - to be sure, could you provide me with the correct address where I can download build tools?

Comment: Address? Are you not doing it with the node module?